# Convert the frequencies of a list elements (table) to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataset, frequency

I have a list like this:

```
 x = c(0,0,1,1,2,3,1,0,4,5,6,4,3,2,1,1,0,2,3)
```

and I need to create a dataframe with frequencies, where col names are the unique elements of my list,and the row contains the frequencies

If I call

```
table(x)
```

I get what I want but it's not dataframe

```
x
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
4 5 3 3 2 1 1
```

I would like to have a data frame like this:

```
> mydf
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 4 5 3 3 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit excessive but

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(table(x))))
```

gives

```
> mydf
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 4 5 3 3 2 1 1
```

Comment: too much going on there, but did the job!